# Boot problem: always boot into the grub command line instead of the grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Could someone help me with this problem, please?

I have ubuntu + win10 installed, and win10 can be booted just fine. When I choose to boot into ubuntu the loader always goes to the grub command line.

If I then set manually the prefix and the root, I can successfully boot into ubuntu, but I have to do this every time. Updating grub didn't work. Boot repair didn't work as well.

The pastebin link:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4Gp8rwZxRW/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Changing the boot loader's folder name from `/boot/efi/EFI/<sth>` to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` fixed the problem. I didn't try but I think using `linux` or any other general os name should work as well.

This seems to be a [well-known bug](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/20187.html).
Kindly greetings to Lenovo's developers.